# Zend Jalali Date

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-date, persian

Does Zend support jalali date and calendar? 
And How can i get that ? 
I tried this:

```
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('fa_IR');
    $date = new Zend_Date();
    $new_date=  Zend_Locale_Format::getDate($date,
        array(
            'date_format' =>Zend_Locale_Format::getDateFormat('fa_IR'),
            'locale' => $locale,
            'fix_date' =>true
            )
        );
```

will not work as I want for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Date` supports `fa_IR` dates, but I don't believe it will do calendar conversions from Gregorian to Jalali. You will have to set date manually. However, here is how you use `Zend_Locale` with `Zend_Date` for `fa_IR`

```
// Manual conversion from Gregorian date 7/7/2011 to Jalali date 1390/4/16
$date   = new Zend_Date('1390/4/16');  
$date->setLocale('fa_IR');
echo $date->toString('F j, Y, g:i a');
// prints آوریل 16, 1390, 12:00 قبل از ظهر
```

**Edit**

I forgot to mention. I have `Zend_Date` `format_type` set to `php` as default format

```
Zend_Date::setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
```

Comment: 16th of Tir (4th month in Jalali calendar) is 6th of July **NOT**  16th of April (4th month in Gregorian ). You cannot enter a Jalali date for first argument.

Comment: `آوریل 16, 1390`  means 16th of April of 1390.